# Using spring in a stand alone jar for dependency injectection

Tags: spring

Am a total beginner with spring framework and trying to know if it even fits my use case, before investing time learning it.

I'm responsible for a stand alone java project(used as a jar by a server) which basically serves requests from a server, and in turn makes service calls to various internal services. 
This standalone java project, currently has all of its service calls hard coded. I want to use Spring to inject dependencies so I can make this stuff testable.

I have no idea how spring works. Does it even hold for standalone jars or is it only for 'running applications'?

If I make my standalone project 'spring enabled', when the server uses my jar, will it automagically work by creating beans or is there some requirement from the server side?

Comment: Please read chapter [3. The IoC container](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/beans.html) of the [Spring Framework Reference Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/) for detailed information. Have a good reading!

Comment: Thanks. That is always an option, but was wondering if someone familiar with Spring can just say yes/no (assuming its a yes/no question) so I can read that 100 page documentation, if it is possible to do what am trying to do in the first place.

Comment: Well effort was made to figure out Spring could be a possible solution by reading the basics about spring and that it helps with injections. My question, I think, is too specific to be able to figure out from their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes, you can use Spring in a standalone jar-application ("console application", if you will), we do it all the time at work. You just need to create the ApplicationContext yourself when your application starts, see for example here: http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/java/load-spring-application-context-file-java-swing-application

This is just one example I pulled straight out of Google, there are probably numerous others. Still, you really need to read at least the basics from the [Spring documentation](https://spring.io/docs/) to get started, otherwise you'll probably hit a wall pretty soon.